# Global Object Literals

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I created global var in main,like :

on mainPage1.js

```
$(#search).click(){ 
text = "string from main";
openChildWindow(searchwindow.jsp);
});
```

on mainPage2.js

```
$(#search).click(){ 
text = "string from main";
openChildWindow(searchwindow.jsp);//same window opening by mainPage1
});
```

on commonSearch.js, i do access the var to display in input

```
$("#myInput").val(window.opener.text);
window.opener.text = ""; // and just reset thevalue to empty
```

To avoid using globals from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices), that I can use object literals,so I come up with like this :

On mainPage1.js

```
myNameSpace = function(){
  var text= null;
  function init(){...}
  return{ init:init }
}();
```

On mainPage2.js

```
myNameSpace = function(){
  var text= null;
  function init(){...}
  return{ init:init }
}();
```

so on commonSearch.js

i just use `myNameSpace.text` to access it?
Since ill be using common search window invoked by different pages,I haven't renamed my namespace, I think I was not able to solve the globals but I just created a global objects then. Can someone please enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get and set the value of `text` (from outside of the object literal), you can also return a function that returns the value of `text` and another function to set the value of `text`.

```js
    var myNameSpace = function() {
      var text = 'nothing';

      function init() {
        text = 'init';
      }
      return {
        init: init,
        getText: function() {
          return text;
        },
        setText: function(newText) {
          text = newText;
        }
      }
    }();
    console.log(myNameSpace.getText());
    myNameSpace.init();
    console.log(myNameSpace.getText());
    myNameSpace.setText('set');
    console.log(myNameSpace.getText());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, so its ok that I have same namespaces?

Comment: If they are named the same and are included on the same page, then one would invariably overwrite the other. If this is code that is included on multiple pages, you may want to consider putting it in a separate javascript file and including the file where necessary.